# Create a mapping for Vim's command-line that escapes the contents of a register before inserting it

Tags: vim, escaping

Suppose that I have a document like this, and I want to search for all occurences of the URL:

```
Vim resources: [http://example.com/search?q=vim][q]
...
[q]: http://example.com/search?q=vim
```

I don't want to type it out in full, so I'll place my cursor on the first URL, and run `"uyi[` to yank it into the 'u' register. Now to search for it, I'd like to just paste the contents of that register into the search field by running:

```
/\V<c-r>u<CR>
```

This results in Vim searching for the string 'http:' - because the '/' character terminates the search field.

I can get around the problem by running this instead:

```
/\V<c-r>=escape(@u, '\/')<CR><CR>
```

But it's a lot of typing!

How can I create a mapping for Vim's commandline that simplifies this workflow?

My ideal workflow would go something like this:

- press `/\V` to bring up the search prompt, and use very nomagic mode
- hit ctrl-x to trigger the custom mapping (ctrl-x is available)
- Vim listens for the next key press... (pressing `<Esc>` would cancel)
- pressing 'u' would escape the contents of the 'u' register, and insert on the command line

Comment: I currently use `*` in visual mode. I have some homemade plugin based off of this script: http://amix.dk/blog/post/19334

Comment: @PeterRincker - yeah, I use [something like that](https://github.com/bronson/vim-visual-star-search) too! Vim's own documentation suggests a [similar mapping](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#visual-search), although it's a little half-baked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
cnoremap <c-x> <c-r>=<SID>PasteEscaped()<cr>
function! s:PasteEscaped()
  " show some kind of feedback
  echo ":".getcmdline()."..."

  " get a character from the user
  let char = getchar()

  if char == "\<esc>"
    return ''
  else
    let register_content = getreg(nr2char(char))
    return escape(register_content, '\/')
  endif
endfunction
```

By the way, something that might be useful to know (if you don't already) is that you can use `?` as the delimiter for `:s`. Which means that you could write a search-and-replace for an url like so:

```
:s?http://foo.com?http://bar.com?g
```

Comment: I didn't draw attention to it in my original question, but I deliberately used a URL that included both '/' and '?' characters. If the search target only included one of those two, then you could dial up the search prompt using the other one, avoiding the need to escape anything.

Comment: You're right about that, I failed to notice the question marks early enough.

Answer (score 8):

I've accepted [Andrew Radev's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400743/create-a-mapping-for-vims-command-line-that-escapes-the-contents-of-a-register-b/7401308#7401308), which solved the hard parts. But here's the version that I've added to my vimrc file, which adds a couple of enhancements:

```
cnoremap <c-x> <c-r>=<SID>PasteEscaped()<cr>
function! s:PasteEscaped()
  echo "\\".getcmdline()."\""
  let char = getchar()
  if char == "\<esc>"
    return ''
  else
    let register_content = getreg(nr2char(char))
    let escaped_register = escape(register_content, '\'.getcmdtype())
    return substitute(escaped_register, '\n', '\\n', 'g')
  endif
endfunction
```

This should work:

- whether you use `/` or `?` (to search forwards, or backwards)
- and when the pasted register includes multiple lines

Also, I changed the prompt. While waiting for a register, the prompt switches to `\` - which seems like a suitable cue for 'PasteEscaped'. Also, I've appended a `"`, which mimics Vim's behavior after pressing `<c-r>` at the command line.

If you've any further suggestions for improvements, please leave a comment.

Comment: will it work for `:s/` too? What about nicher ones with custom pattern-delimiters like `:s;` ?

Answer (score 2):

How about different workflow?  For example, creating your own operator to search target text as is:

```
" https://gist.github.com/1213642
" Requiement: https://github.com/kana/vim-operator-user
map YourFavoriteKeySequence  <Plug>(operator-search-target-text)
call operator#user#define('search-target-text', 'OperatorSerachTargetText')
function! OperatorSerachTargetText(motion_wise)
  execute 'normal!' '`['.operator#user#visual_command_from_wise_name(a:motion_wise).'`]"xy'
  let @/ = '\V' . escape(substitute(@x, '[\r\n]$', '', ''), '\')
  normal! n
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

I like @nelstrom's solution and made a small change to support escaping [ and ].

```
 cnoremap <c-x> <c-r>=<SID>PasteEscaped()<cr>
 function! s:PasteEscaped()
   echo "\\".getcmdline()."\""
   let char = getchar()
   if char == "\<esc>"
     return ''
   else
     let register_content = getreg(nr2char(char))
     let escaped_register = escape(register_content, '\'.getcmdtype())
     let escaped_register2 = substitute(escaped_register,'[','\\[','g')
     let escaped_register3 = substitute(escaped_register2,']','\\]','g')
     return substitute(escaped_register3, '\n', '\\n', 'g')
   endif
 endfunction
```