# what will be the regex for this?

Tags: xml, regex, vim

I have an xml file which I am editing manually. The xml file structure is as follows:

```
<order>
    <id>1</field>
    <current_execution_status>REGENERATED</field>
    <generated_time>2012-12-01 17:55:00</field>
    <generation_status>UNKNOWN</field>
    <priority>0</field>
    <type>NORMAL</field>
    <assigned_vehicle>1</field>
    <assigned_drop_location>1</field>
    <assigned_pick_location>1</field>
    <generation_by_user_name>ABC</field>
    <material>1</field>
    <order_cancel_detail />
    <order_drop_detail />
    <order_pick_detail />
</order>
```

I wanted to replace each occurrence of `field` with respective "field names" from in front of the values. For e.g. `<id>1</field>` should become `<id>1</id>`, `<current_execution_status>REGENERATED</current_execution_status>`, etc. like this way. But not getting what should be my regex for this in `vim`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
:%s/<\([^<>]*\)>\([^<>]*\)<\/field>/<\1>\2<\/\1>/
```

Comment: +1 because this takes the trouble my sloppy version doesn't (`[^<>]*`)

Comment: @Didier: Yes it worked. But this took more time than the one provided by @Faiz. I think its only because of `([^<>]*\)`, if I understood it correctly. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Both work; @Didier's suggestion is more 'strict' in that it's a more 'proper' match for XML: `/<.*>/` is a bit loose compared to `/<[^<>]*>/` but for your case, it doesn't make any difference at all. I +1'd @Didier's because it's a good habit to be as precise as you can when writing regex's. But of course, when you just want to quickly do something in `vim` to save a few minutes, who cares? :-)

Comment: @Faiz: Yes you are right. And anyways I wanted this one time only. I am nowhere going to need it in anywhere in project. So it was only for the test purpose.\

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
:%s/<\(.*\)>\(.*\)<\/field>$/<\1>\2<\/\1>/
```

Things to note about Vim's regexps:

1. Captures/grouping happen with `\(` and ')' and not '(', ')'. ('(', ')') just means the 
   actual characters for open/close parens.
2. Capture memory is `\1`, `\2` etc.
3. `/` needs to be escaped as usual `\/`

Comment: Thanks...that worked...awsome regex. I think I need to learn more about regex and especially vim.

Comment: @srahul07 - Escaping can become tedious... This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400743/create-a-mapping-for-vims-command-line-that-escapes-the-contents-of-a-register) has a good solution that will help.  Yank the field to a register, then when in command mode, you can put an escaped version of the register into the command line with C-X. It's a bit like C-R.